# Triple level associations in phpactiverecord

Tags: associations, eager-loading, phpactiverecord

Right now if I try to eager load more than two objects deep in phpactiverecord, I get an error.

Is something such as this:

```
$conditions['include'] = array( 'playlists' => array('playlist_songs' =>array('song')));
User::find('first', $conditions);
```

Just one level too much to try to retrieve? 
I'm getting an error `Undefined offset: 0` whenever I try to use an association 3 levels deep.
Thanks for any help or insight :D.

Edit:

So I've found a pattern that's a little odd.
If I have `array('playlist_songs'=>array('song'=>array('album')));`, the eager load will break for me. But if I add another association to the array, it then works correctly.
`array('playlist_songs'=>array('song','song','song','song'=>array('album')));`

I used 'song' multiple times in that array just to make the fix very apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fixed this for myself by changing line 247 of Table.php in execute_eager_load from

```
if (is_array($name))
{
            $nested_includes = count($name) > 1 ? $name : $name[0];//<-- this line
            $name = $index;
}
```

to

```
if (is_array($name))
{
            $nested_includes = count($name) > 0 ? $name : $name[0];
            $name = $index;
}
```

Comment: This is half pulling out life saving! I'll give it some testing sometime today or tomorrow.

Comment: That was supposed to say hair*.  Looking back, that comment looks very inappropriate...

Comment: Great to see you got this into the repo Anther thanks for the follow through!

Answer (score 1):

This should work. An example I've just tested this my own code:

```
$model = MyItem::find('first',array('include' => array('Group' => array('SomeGroupFeature'))));
```

The only thing I can think of is that you don't have any results in one of the things, or your conditions contains something else from a previous use of the array?

Comment: For your example to match the question exactly, the includes array would need to look like this:  `array('include' => array('Group' => array('SomeGroupFeature' =>array('third_thing'))))` ;)

Comment: I'm going to do some more testing and see if it indeed has to do with empty results, since I am finding situations where it does indeed work as expected...