# Access nested eager loaded model without causing N+1 queries in php activerecord

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

I am loading a model called **Maintenance_Record** with a nested eager load like so:

```
Maintenance_Record::find('all', array('include' => array('maintenance_plan' => array('user') ) ) );
```

As you can see, I am eager loading **Maintenance_Plan** and **User**. **User** is nested within **Maintenance_Plan**. I want to use the **User** model from the **Maintenance_Record** model in my view. I have a loop in one of my views like this:

```
foreach( $records as $record )
    echo $record->maintenance_plan->user->first_name;
```

However, when I look at the SQL, activerecord is loading each **User** model per call in the loop resulting in N+1 calls.

When I var_dump the **Maintenance_Record** model, the **Maintenance_Plan** and **User** are being loaded correctly. So the question is how do I access the nested eager loaded model without causing N+1 queries?

Comment: What do the relationships look like in your Model?  You could call array('user', 'through' => 'maintanace_plan').  Or you could try call it like $record->maintenance_plan->user[0]->first_name;

Answer (score 0):

[Triple level associations in phpactiverecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983803/triple-level-associations-in-phpactiverecord)

It's a bug that hasn't gotten much attention, but I'm fairly certain it's what you're encountering right here.